# find_or_create_by_facebook_id method not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, undefined, facebooker

I'm trying to find out where this function comes from.  Any one have any clue?  It's used by this:

http://github.com/fluidtickets/facebooker-authlogic-bridge

with a working example here:

http://facebooker-authlogic-bridge.heroku.com

Downloading the code, it throws: `undefined method 'find_or_create_by_facebook_id' for #<Class:0xb04dd1c>`

I have no clue where this function comes from.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveRecord creates dynamic finders based on columns in your database. So for example if you have a user with a username attribute then activerecord creates a number of dynamic finders:

```
find_by_username
find_or_initialize_by_username #=> calls new if not found
find_or_create_by_username #=> calls create if not found
```

You can string a few attributes together like

```
find_by_username_and_email
```

To get back to your problem - I suspect that you haven't run some required migration that adds the facebook_id to your users table in the db and therefore ActiveRecord isn't adding the dynamic finder for facebook_id to the class.

Comment: I am having this same issue of facebook_id not being added onto the db.  I've ran bundle exec rake db:migrate and have 2 databases. I'm also using SQLite. Could that be the reason why? I either get the error mentioned above, OR, `You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]`... 
when I change up the code a bit, which I think means that my array of info is empty. I think that narrows me down to this reasoning.